# Undefined variable Laravel

Tags: javascript, php, laravel

Здравствуйте можете подсказать причину ошибки Undefined variable при передачи коллекции в шаблон blade?

JS

```
 <script>
        let token = document.querySelector('input[name="_token"]').value
        fetch('/showMyPosts', {
            method: "post",
            body: token
        })
    </script>
```

View

```
<div class="" id="main_content">
                       @foreach($posts as $post)
                            <div class="card mb-3">
                                <!-- Card header START -->
                                <div class="card-header border-0 pb-0">
                                    <div class="d-flex align-items-center justify-content-between">
                                        <div class="d-flex align-items-center">
                                            <!-- Avatar -->
                                            <div class="avatar avatar-story me-2">
                                                <a href="#!"> <img class="avatar-img rounded-circle" src="{{$post->author_img}}" alt=""> </a>
                                            </div>
                                            <!-- Info -->
                                            <div>
                                                <div class="nav nav-divider">
                                                    <h6 class="nav-item card-title mb-0"> <a href="#!">{{$post->name.''.$post->lastname}} </a></h6>
                                                    <span class="nav-item small"> 2hr</span>
                                                </div>
                                                <p class="mb-0 small">{{$post->about}}</p>
                                            </div>
                                        </div>
                                        <!-- Card feed action dropdown START -->
                                        <div class="dropdown">
                                            <a href="#" class="text-secondary btn btn-secondary-soft-hover py-1 px-2" id="cardFeedAction1" data-bs-toggle="dropdown" aria-expanded="false">
                                                <i class="bi bi-three-dots"></i>
                                            </a>
                                            <!-- Card feed action dropdown menu -->
                                            <ul class="dropdown-menu dropdown-menu-end" aria-labelledby="cardFeedAction1">
                                                <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="#"> <i class="bi bi-bookmark fa-fw pe-2"></i>Save post</a></li>
                                                <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="#"> <i class="bi bi-person-x fa-fw pe-2"></i>Unfollow lori ferguson </a></li>
                                                <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="#"> <i class="bi bi-x-circle fa-fw pe-2"></i>Hide post</a></li>
                                                <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="#"> <i class="bi bi-slash-circle fa-fw pe-2"></i>Block</a></li>
                                                <li><hr class="dropdown-divider"></li>
                                                <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="#"> <i class="bi bi-flag fa-fw pe-2"></i>Report post</a></li>
                                            </ul>
                                        </div>
                                        <!-- Card feed action dropdown END -->
                                    </div>
                                </div>

                                <!-- Card header END -->
                                <!-- Card body START -->
                                <div class="card-body">
                                    <p>{{$post->content}}</p>
                                    <!-- Card img -->
                                    <img class="card-img" style="height: 500px" src="{{$post->img}}" alt="">
                                    <!-- Feed react START -->
                                    <!-- Card share action dropdown menu -->
                                    <ul class="dropdown-menu dropdown-menu-end" aria-labelledby="cardShareAction8">
                                        <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="#"> <i class="bi bi-envelope fa-fw pe-2"></i>Send via Direct Message</a></li>
                                        <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="#"> <i class="bi bi-bookmark-check fa-fw pe-2"></i>Bookmark </a></li>
                                        <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="#"> <i class="bi bi-link fa-fw pe-2"></i>Copy link to post</a></li>
                                        <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="#"> <i class="bi bi-share fa-fw pe-2"></i>Share post via …</a></li>
                                        <li><hr class="dropdown-divider"></li>
                                        <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="#"> <i class="bi bi-pencil-square fa-fw pe-2"></i>Share to News Feed</a></li>
                                    </ul>
                                    </li>
                                    <!-- Card share action END -->
                                    </ul>
                                    <!-- Feed react END -->
                                    <!-- Card body END -->
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        @endforeach
```

Controller

```
public function showMyPosts(){
        $author_id = auth()->user()->getAuthIdentifier();
        $posts = Posts::where('author_id', $author_id)->get();
        return view('profile.edit', compact('posts'));
    }
```

Router

```
Route::post('/showMyPosts', [PostController::class, 'showMyPosts'])->middleware('auth');
```

При загрузке страницы выдает ошибку Undefined variable $posts
Я догадываюсь, что в этой ошибке замешан js, но исправить не получается, подскажите пожалуйста, как мне разобраться с данной ошибкой

Comment: Для начала проверьте что $posts содержит в себе хоть какие-то данные.

Comment: 1. Какая именно ошибка? В какой строчке и какую переменную не находит?

Comment: 2. Если $posts, попробуйте перед `return view` написать `dd( compact('posts') );` и проверить что именно передается

Comment: Такс , отвечу всем по очереди, переменная не пустая, не видит во 2 строчке кода View

Answer (score 0):

Если вы возвращаете в контроллере view вам не нужен fetch запрос. Вы при переходе по пути `/showMyPosts` будете получать переданную вами страницу с переменными. И поменяйте метод `post` на метод `get`, так как метод post не возвратит вам view. А данные о пользователе вы можете получить и в самом blade используя `Auth::id()` как пример.